# handleSubmit is not defined? what does that mean? whenever I execute white screen is shown. please solve the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

handleSubmit is not defined? what does that mean? whenever I execute white screen is shown. please solve the problem. handleSubmit is not defined? what does that mean? whenever I execute white screen is shown. please solve the problem. handleSubmit is not defined? what does that mean? whenever I execute white screen is shown. please solve the problem.

function Data() {

```
FormData = () => {
    const [fname, setFname] = useState('');
    const [lname, setLname] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/server', {
                fname,
                lname,
            });
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}

return (

    < div >
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                First Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.FormData.fname} onChange={(e) => this.FormData.setFname(e.target.value)}></input>
            </label>
            <label>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.FormData.lname} onChange={(e) => this.FormData.setLname(e.target.value)}></input>
            </label>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div >

)
```

}

Comment: Your `handleSubmit()` function is inside `FormData` component, that is why you can't use it inside `Data`. Better question is why are you declaring a component inside another component?

Comment: @Balaj -- Don't repeat yourself x times just to satisfy the editor's demand for a minimum of characters. Invest your energy into more details allowing people to help you better. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You've added `handleSubmit` in a place where the `return` statement cannot access it. Please use this:

```
const Data = () => {
    const [fname, setFname] = useState('');
    const [lname, setLname] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/server', {
                fname,
                lname,
            });
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (

        < div >
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    First Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.FormData.fname} onChange={(e) => this.FormData.setFname(e.target.value)}></input>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Last Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.FormData.lname} onChange={(e) => this.FormData.setLname(e.target.value)}></input>
                </label>
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    
    )
}
```